# Почему запуск скрипта в cmd происходит не с той версии python которая указанная в переменной PATH?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-2.7

Установлены 2 версии Python, Python 2.7.15 и Python 3.8.6, в переменной PATH указан путь к Python 3.8.6, полный путь указанный в PATH `D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python_3.8;D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python_3.8\Scripts;D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Projects_Training` Так же в PATH указан путь до моего скрипта, запускаю скрипт из пути `D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Projects_Training\Test2.py` выводя версию python через `sys.version` и пишется что версия python с помощью которой я запустил скрипт это `Python 2.7.15`, как заставить запускаться по умолчанию скрипты с версией `Python 3.8.6`?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте файловые ассоциации с py файлами.

Comment: попробуйте просто в консоли написать python Test2.py или python3 Test2.py

Comment: @viilpe в реестре? или через меню выбора программ?, через меню выбора программ выбираю python.exe из пути Python_3.8 и ставлю по умолчанию, это не дает никакого эффекта

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко через меню выбора программ вы выбираете для текущего пользователя, однако на скриншоте у вас консоль от Администратора, а это видимо другой пользователь с другими ассоциациями.

Comment: @viilpe как мне сменить ассоциацию с файлами .py для Администратора?

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко либо залогиниться от него, либо использовать команды [ftype](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype) и [assoc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) в консоли от администратора.

Comment: @viilpe Спасибо! Помогло

Comment: Еще как вариант обратите внимание на первую строку в вашем скрипте, Сейчас она просто занимает место. Там как раз можно указать путь к python. Обычно полезно при использовании виртуального окружения. `#! C:\Python\Python3.8\python.exe`

Comment: @Kers в винде это не работает

Comment: @eri Прекрасно все работает в винде! Регулярно запускаю двойным кликом скрипты для которых нужно вирт окружение. В моем случае правда прописывается относительный путь. `#! venv\Scripts\python.exe`.

Comment: @Kers  Возможно ли применить тот же трюк к версиям питона что не находятся в вирт окружении?

Comment: @Анатолий Михеенко Это не имеет значения так так указывается просто путь к нужному нам python.exe, а где он находится вопрос вторичный. Из минусов только то что не все IDE это понимают. Например при запуске из sublime будет запускаться системный питон. Но через консоль или двойным кликом все работает прекрасно

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, эта строка работает только в Unix системах, а для платформы Windows эта строка не имеет никакого значения.

Comment: "эта строка" - это какая?

Comment: Единственное отличие `Windows` от `Unix` в том, что `Windows` сначала ищет файл для запуска в текущем каталоге, а потом уже в путях из `PATH`, а `Unix` сразу лезет в `PATH`, а текущий путь смотрит только при явном указании `./` как пути запуска.

Comment: Прошу прощения, свой комментарий написал как ответ. Я имел ввиду строку в начале файла "#!/usr/bin/env python3".

Comment: А, вы про shebang, мне казалось в вопросе было только про PATH. Я посмотрел комментарии, теперь понятно.